# navigator.contacts is undefined

Tags: android, jquery, cordova, contacts

I want to view all contacts but the navigator.contacts is undefined.

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-contacts
cordova build android
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(document).on('deviceready', function(){ 
    alert('something'); 
  }, false); //it doesn't even alert something;
  console.log(navigator.contacts);
});
```

I have take it out of document ready either. NO RESULT :(

Someone said the problem can be fixed by removing and adding platform android and adding plugin again, however it didn't!
I have also put the script tag to the end, in order that the page to be loaded then run the scripts.

Comment: Thanks for editing :)

Answer (score 0):

I tried this code sometime back in my project and it worked:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
});

function onDeviceReady() {      
     $('#contact').click( function() 
        {   
            try {               
                var contact = navigator.contacts.create({"displayName": "CordovaUser"});
                var phoneNumbers = [];
                phoneNumbers[0] = new ContactField('work', '212-555-1234', false);
                phoneNumbers[1] = new ContactField('mobile', '917-555-5432', true); // preferred number
                phoneNumbers[2] = new ContactField('home', '203-555-7890', false);
                contact.phoneNumbers = phoneNumbers;                
                contact.save();
                alert("Contact created successfully");
            }
            catch(err) {
                alert("Plugin Error - " + err.message);
            }

        });     
}
```

Comment: it is creating, however I want to fetch the contacts user has. Could you change it to get the contacts please?

Comment: @codepro you have a sample here - https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-contacts#navigatorcontactsfind